# Opening Files From Any Directory

Tags: python, file, file-io, operating-system

I'm writing this basic code that runs files on my computer but right now it can only open files from the directory it is in. is there a way to open files from anywhere on my computer or would I have to give the path for the file.

Here is my code:

```
def run(filename):
    try:
        import os
        os.startfile(filename)
    except:
        WindowsError
        print ("Thats not a valid file name")

while True:

    filename = raw_input("Filename: ")
    run(filename)
    x = raw_input("Would you like to open another file? [y/n]: ")
    if x == "n":
        quit()
```

This opens and runs the files fine but only from the directory its saved in.

Comment: its not clear what you want to do... are you wanting to search your whole computer for a file named "X" or whatever?  what if you have `"C:\A\file1.txt"` and `"C:\B\file1.txt"` ... which one would you pick?

Comment: As @JoranBeasley pointed out, if you want to open files in directories other than where your script is at, you will have to qualify the name with the complete path.

Comment: i was just wondering if there was a way i could access files anywhere in my computer

Comment: If you're trying to access any program on the PATH, the way the DOS prompt does, you can do that. If you're trying to access any file anywhere on the computer… you have to search for it (whether by walking the whole tree, by asking Desktop Search, or otherwise).

Comment: FYI, `WindowsError` should be on the same line as `except`, i.e. `except WindowsError:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def run(filename):
    for directoy,files,dirs in os.walk("C:\\"):
        if filename in files:
           return os.startfile(os.path.join(directory,filename))
```

fair warning it may be slow ...

Comment: thats what i wanted i guess i knew it would be slow because it has to search for the file but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this a couple of different ways

either use entire paths

or change the directory its looking at

changing the directory is pretty easy

```
os.chdir("PATH TO DIRECTORY")
```